# android c code array debug using logcat

Tags: android, arrays, debugging, android-ndk, logcat

On my native code I want to debug the byte[] array passed for android app. I want to store the byte array into a file or display it in the logcat. I could covert each char to string and print it into the logcat in my c code. Is their a better way to debug the array in the c code?

Comment: Your basic options are to write it to the log, write it to a file, or attach a debugger and poke at it.  How big is the array?  What's in it (is it something visual, like bitmap data)?

Comment: the array will be a image buffer I am sending from the android side.. [1280 X 720 ], I would like to log it so that i could check couple of frames afterwards. I want to write to a file or dump it using the logcat. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a WritableByteChannel to dump the byte[] buffer into a file.

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/"+filename+".yuv"));
WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(output);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
channel.write(byteBuffer);
channel.close();
output.close();
```

Comment: He seems to be looking for a solution in native code, not Java (although that's not entirely clear).

Comment: Thanks Shashika for the suggestion, but Fadden is correct I am looking for a solution in my C code.